# Reading a postfix expression as a string from a txt file

Tags: c++, stack, prefix, postfix-notation

This is part of my C++ assignment.  I need to write three functions in the project.  When i start my work, I found a huge problem, the first function.

First of all, the program is like this:

1. Open the postfix expression file
2. Use getline to read line by line (each line is an expression)
3. Evaluate the expression step by step

I know that I need to call the function to know the next operand and then to calculate the intermediate result.  The `nextOperand` function returns the value of the next operand (datatype: double) that starts at index I of the input string.

This is what I have now:

```
double nextOperand(const string& expr, int& i)
{
    // You can make use of the function stod(string) string-to-double,
    // and the function substring() to extract an operand from the expression:
    // Example:
    //   string myExpression = "1.5 2.3 +";
    //   int pos = 0;
    //   int len = 3;
    //   string opderand = myExpression.substr(pos, len); 
    //   double value = stod(opderand);
    stack<char> temp;
    string temp1;

    while(expr[i] != ' ' && !isOperator(expr[i]))
    {
        temp.push(expr[i]);
        i++;
    }

    while(!temp.empty())
    {
        temp1 = temp.top() + temp1;
        temp.pop();
    }
    if(temp1 != "\0")
    {
        double value = stod(temp1);
        return value;
    }
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

The function to evaluate postfix and prefix expressions are not yet programmed.  I wish to finish this `nextOperand` function first to continue.

Comment: What's your actual question? This just looks like a summary of your progress so far on some homework you've been assigned.

Comment: @Choc13 i want to ask if my function is implementable or not and also i am confused about the way to save the next operand

Comment: Yeah I would imagine your function is implementable if your assignment wants you to implement it. I have also seen an example of this kind of thing in The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition) by Stroustup.

Comment: Your first `while` loop increments `i` and also calls `expr[i]`. This could lead to `i` running out of bounds. You add something like: `if (i == expr.size()) break;`. Also that `at` method for `string` is a safer way to access elements than using the `[]` operator. `at` throws exceptions for out of bounds input, whereas `[]` can lead to undefined behaviour when `i` goes out of range.

Comment: What do you mean by 'save the next operand'. Surely `nextOperand` just returns the one you have found. You could then either store that in a variable or use it immediately, but that depend on how you plan to use this function to complete the assignment.

Comment: @Choc13 thanks for your suggestions about the book and the while loop thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have over complicated this. I would use the suggestions you have in the comments at the start of the function about using the `substring` function. You could then use something like your first `while` loop to get the index of the first non-operand character. Using the example input of "1.5 2.3 +" as per the comments you could do something like this:

```
int j = i;
while(j < expr.size() && expr.at(j) != ' ' && !isOperator(expr.at(j))) {
        j++;
    }
```

`j` is the variable used to keep track of where the end of the operand is in the string `expr`, `j` should then equal `3` for the example input

Then just do:

```
string operand = expr.substr(i, j); 
return stod(operand);
```

Comment: Note: Not sure what would happen for the case where an operand isn't found an `i == j` after the `while` loop has executed. My guess is that `substring` will return an empty string and you might get weird behaviour with `stod(operand)`. So I'll leave it up to you to put some check in for this condition and handle it appropriately.

Comment: only these few lines can do the task to extract the next operand?

Comment: I haven't tested it and I wouldn't like to claim it would work for any inputs, but given you have comments in your function that look like they are from the teacher, I have assumed the example he has given is the only format you will be accepting. I also, don't know what characters the `isOperator` function returns true for. In fact it might be better to write the loops like this: `while (j < expr.size() && (expr.at(j) == '.' || isNumeral(expr.at(j))` this is more clear about which characters can form an operand, but again I am guessing that they are decimal digits which might not be true.

Comment: Here is the isOperator():
'bool isOperator(char c)
{
 return (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '$');
}'

Comment: So what characters can form a valid operand? Perhaps writing a function called `isValidOperandChar` similar to `isOperator` would be useful.

Comment: i am required to write three functions and not to make any change in other functions or add other functions...so...i cant write the isValidOperandChar function...

Comment: It's not necessary, but it would make the code cleaner, more re-useable, easier to debug etc. Does my solution work? You should accept the answer to close the question if it does.

Comment: It seems work but not sure if the whole stuff will work or not.  But i will still accept the answer.  Thanks for your help^^

Comment: No problem. Hopefully you can figure out the rest now too.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following does not do any error detection.

GCC 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x rpn-calc.cpp

```
#include <array>
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

template <typename OP>
void eval(std::stack<double>& args) {
  OP op;
  auto a2 = args.top();
  args.pop();
  auto a1 = args.top();
  args.pop();
  args.push(op(a1, a2));
}

double eval(std::istream& is, std::stack<double>& args) {
  while (is) {
    std::ws(is);
    if (std::isgraph(is.peek())) {
      double arg = 0.0;
      while (is >> arg) { args.push(arg); }
      is.clear();
      is.unget(); // may have consumed a '+' or a '-'
    }

    std::ws(is);
    if (std::isgraph(is.peek())) {
      char op = 0;
      if (is >> op) {
        switch (op) {
          case '+': eval<std::plus<double>>(args); break;
          case '*': eval<std::multiplies<double>>(args); break;
          case '-': eval<std::minus<double>>(args); break;
          case '/': eval<std::divides<double>>(args); break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return args.top();
}

int main() {
  std::array<std::string, 7> tests = {{
    "1.0 2.0 +",
    "1.0 2.0 *",
    "1.0 2.0 -",
    "1.0 2.0 /",
    "1.0 2.0 3.0 + +",
    "1.0 2.0 + 3.0 *",
    "-1.0 +1.0 +",
  }};

  std::stack<double> env;
  for (int i = 0; i < tests.size(); ++i) {
    std::stringstream str(tests[i]);
    std::cout << eval(str, env) << std::endl;
  }
}
```